# How do I import a Second -Life Avitar (XML file) into Blender?

Tags: import, conversion

I have recently downloaded Blender 2.71 as I thought maybe it would have the import/export option for xml that 2.70 did not. I have only been using blender for two months. I have not used any other game engine software. I'm learning this for rigging purposes for a job that I just got.

I need to import a .xml into blender since that is the type of file the platform uses.

**Is there an addon that I can put into Blender for xml and if so, how do I install it to blender?** (<<< this is the VERY specific question) Every tutorial on rigging avatars shows how to get the avatar from Second Life into Blender and EVERY single video shows exactly what I commented. They then go into Blender and have the option in their older versions of Blender to IMPORT .xml. So.... again, even though I asked very specifically, is there an addon that I can put in my Blender's Addon folder that allows Blender 2.71 to use/import/open/(whatever other word you would like to use here for the same meaning) .xml so that I can actually begin learning how to rig SecondLife avatars.

Thanks so much!

I have tried using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJIrQw-RMd0&list=PL11D6E99BB51A2BB2&index=1

However that website does not work anymore.

I then tried using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELC4B0PAXDs&index=2&list=PL11D6E99BB51A2BB2

However Wiz Daxter's pluggin does not work either. After extracting the files to the addon folder for blender, the next step is to open blender, go to user preferences, go to addons, choose import/export and enable pluggin. The pluggin is not in the list.

So I'm out of ideas on how to download a pluggin, addon, or extension thing to make Blender accept the Appearance to xml avatar. Second Life only allows you to take your avatar from game in this fashion.

Comment: XML isn't a 3D format - its a markup language - used to describe lots of things, You may be thinking of **X3D** or **Collada** (both are based on XML), however neither use the `*.XML` file extension by convention.

Comment: I'm importing an avatar from SecondLife. The only option is xml.

Comment: In that case you should update your Q, to ask about second-life-avatar XML files. But you may be better to ask about what you actually are trying to do, (Take a model from second-life into Blender?)

Comment: The way to take a model from second-life into Blender is to enter the game, go to the Develop menu, choose the Avatar submenu, choose character tests menu, then choose Appearance to XML. That is NOT the issue. My issue is that Blender does not let you import xml. I specifically asked in my question how to import xml into blender because that IS what I'm trying to do.

Comment: This is like asking how to import an email attachment, `ZIP` or `ISO` into Blender, `XML` is just a container, not a 3D format. For example, blender stores its UI themes in `XML` format.

Comment: Thank you. I'm currently trying to see if I can have two versions of Blender on my computer. Version 2.63 is compatible with Wiz Daxter's pluggin for what I'm trying to do, however I have to use 2.71 for work.

Comment: @Candice I tried the Wiz Daxter's pluggin on the 2.71 version of blender, and it work! Be sure to be on a 32bit version of blender!

Comment: @lucblender I cannot seem to find the pluggin in the menu to enable. I even tried to just go to import to see if it automatically enabled the addon and it did not. Do you have any advice as to troubleshoot how I somehow messed up installing it. I followed the directions exactly and it doesn't have a new addon in the menu.

Comment: @Candice So for the installation I've put the 'SAV' folder from the addon to C:\Program Files (x86)\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.71\scripts\addons this is the folder of my 32 bit version of blender. Then in blender the addon is in the Impot-Export Section and its name is Import Secondlif Mesh and Skeleton

Comment: @lucblender Is there anyway I could speak with you via Skype or is there some way I can put screenshots of what I have going on so that maybe you can see what I've done wrong? I have the folder in the same location. I do not have the option of Import Secondlife Mesh and Skeleton in the import/Export Section of Blender, no matter which version I load. V 2.63 or 2.71. Also I'm using Windows XP and everything on this computer is 32 bit. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said the Wiz Daxter [addon](http://wiz-bg.blogspot.ch/p/main.html) is perfect for the importation of secondlife XML file.

If you have trouble for the installation here are some advice:

First this addon work only for **32 bits** version of [blender](http://www.blender.org/download/).

After downloading the Wiz Daxter addon, **the 1.0.9 version**, extract it in you blender folder. In my case it's :

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.71\scripts\addons*

/!\ Put only the **SLAV** folder and not Blender263_SLAV_109 in your addon folder!

Now you can enable your addon in the user-preferences that you can acces with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>.

Then the addon is in the Impot-Export Section and its name is Import Secondlif Mesh and Skeleton.

Comment: Thank you ever so much. This worked perfectly. I also want to add that this worked for Blender v. 2.71

Comment: @Candice If this has answer has answered your question, consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark above.

Answer (score 0):

Install the addon called "Avastar" from: http://blog.machinimatrix.org/avastar/

Avastar is a Blender Addon for making 3D Content for Second Life. Avastar supports the entire 3D production chain:

Comment: Please add a bit more info to the answer. What this is doing? why it should be used?